# Flatten JSON data to individual columns

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

I am working upon Twitter streaming data and I am having an output like this:

```
    "data": {
    "author_id": "1318123716522479616",
    "created_at": "2020-11-05T04:18:21.000Z",
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "end": 107,
                "start": 86,
                "tag": "MilliHesaplarYanyana"
            }
        ],
        "mentions": [
            {
                "end": 15,
                "start": 3,
                "username": "MilliTaakip"
            }
        ]
    },
    "id": "1324204381177323520",
    "lang": "tr",
    "text": "RT @MilliTaakip: Milli hesaplar\u0131m\u0131z\u0131n g\u00fc\u00e7lenmesi i\u00e7in\nCumhurba\u015fkan\u0131m\u0131z\u0131n talimat\u0131yla,\n#MilliHesaplarYanyana \u00e7al\u0131\u015fmas\u0131n\u0131 destekliyoruz;\n\n\ud83c\uddf9\ud83c\uddf7\u2026"
}
```

}

I want to extract specific information like the hashtags from this data and store them in my database.
I tried using multiple ways like `json.normalize` ,`flatten_json` but it does not work. I get the following as my output

[image]

here's my code:

```
def connect_to_endpoint(url, headers):
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, stream=True, params=payload)
print(response.status_code)

for response_line in response.iter_lines():
    if response_line:

        # print(ndjson.dumps(json_response["data"]["text"], indent=4, sort_keys=True))

        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="tweetData", user="postgres", password="pass", host="localhost", port="5432")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # cc

        try:

            data = json.loads(response_line.decode('utf-8'))
            index = 0
            #for created at
            var2 = json.loads(response_line.decode('utf-8'))["data"]["text"]

    


            # define a list of keywords
            keywords = ('biden', 'election', 'trump','stocks')
            if any(keyword in var2.lower() for keyword in keywords):
                df= pd.json_normalize(data)
                dffinal=pd.DataFrame(df)
                engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:root@localhost:5432/tweetData')

                dffinal.to_sql("new-tweets", engine,if_exists='append',dtype = {'relevant_column':sqlalchemy.types.JSON})

                print("loaded")
            else:
                print("none")

            conn.commit()
            index += 1
            cur.close()
        except IOError as io:
            print("ERROR!")

if response.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception(
        "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(
            response.status_code, response.text
        )
    )
```

Please advise on how should I proceed and what errors I have in my approach

EDIT:
Every time I try to retrieve the tweet data, in case there is no entities or no hashtags in the tweet data, it sends an error saying Key Error: 'entities'

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you could use

```
SELECT value ->> 'tag'
FROM jsonb_array_elements(your_json #> '{data,entities,hashtags}') AS x(value);
```

to extract the tags.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But actually I am looking for accessing the hashtag data from the stream and store it in the database. But since it falls under the entities, I am facing a hard time retrieving it.